# How to capture the contents of a UIView and change it into a UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I currently have a view and I would like to change it into a UIImage. I would like to do this because the UIImage class is much better for what I need to do. How would you capture the contents of a UIView and copy the contents into a UIImage?

Thanks,

-David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You will need to include the CoreGraphics framework, and import the CALayer.h:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
```

Comment: I know this is old, but for Retina displays use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, myView.opaque, 0.0);` to avoid a fuzzy looking picture.

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this

```
CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
UIImage *screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
```

That will take a screenshot of the screen, so in theory capturing all of the view's elements and gives you a UIImage to work off of. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, that is quite cool but the problem is it captures the entire main view and I have a tab bar for example in my main view which I don't want in the final UIImage... Any way to get around this?

Thanks in advance,
-David

Comment: you could try cropping the UIImage to the exact x,y coordinates you'll need. If this isn't a good option for you, then this method probably won't work

Comment: You could perhaps make the elements non visible at such stage when the image is captured?

Answer (score 0):

Add Following method to UIView category and use

```
- (UIImage*) capture {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```